# How to deduce the return type of a function object from parameters list?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, projection, visual-c++-2013

I'm trying to write a projection function that could transform a `vector<T>` into a `vector<R>`. Here is an example:

```
auto v = std::vector<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};
auto r1 = select(v, [](int e){return e*e; }); // {1, 4, 9, 16}
auto r2 = select(v, [](int e){return std::to_string(e); }); // {"1", "2", "3", "4"}
```

First attempt:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
std::vector<R> select(std::vector<T> const & c, std::function<R(T)> s)
{
   std::vector<R> v;
   std::transform(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::back_inserter(v), s);
   return v;
}
```

But for

```
auto r1 = select(v, [](int e){return e*e; });
```

I get:

> error C2660: 'select' : function does not take 2 arguments

I have to explicitly call `select<int,int>` to work. I don't like this because the types are redundant.

```
auto r1 = select<int, int>(v, [](int e){return e*e; }); // OK
```

Second attempt:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename Selector>
std::vector<R> select(std::vector<T> const & c, Selector s)
{
   std::vector<R> v;
   std::transform(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::back_inserter(v), s);
   return v;
}
```

The result is same error, function does not take 2 arguments. In this case I actually have to supply a 3rd type argument:

```
auto r1 = select<int, int, std::function<int(int)>>(v, [](int e){return e*e; });
```

Third attempt:

```
template<typename T, typename R, template<typename, typename> class Selector>
std::vector<R> select(std::vector<T> const & c, Selector<T,R> s)
{
   std::vector<R> v;
   std::transform(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::back_inserter(v), s);
   return v;
}
```

For

```
auto r1 = select<int, int, std::function<int(int)>>(v, [](int e){return e*e; });
```

the error is:

> 'select' : invalid template argument for 'Selector', class template expected

For

```
auto r1 = select(v, [](int e){return e*e; });
```

> error C2660: 'select' : function does not take 2 arguments

(I know the last two attempts are not particularly great.)

How can I write this `select()` template function to work for the sample code I put in the beginning?

Comment: Can I ask you what compilateur your using? because for me (using your first attempt) `_select(v, [](int e){return (e);})` doesn't work because cast from lambda -> std::function can't be directly done...

Comment: VC++ 2013 (I forgot to tag that).

Comment: @CollioTV Why shouldn't that cast be possible? The problem here is that type deduction together with a type conversion don't work.

Comment: @leemes because the template fail to be deduced... but Piotr S. find a great work around!

Comment: A bit more boilerplate, but: `std::vector<R> r; std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(r), [](auto x) { return f(x); });` [You probably want to add `r.reserve(v.size())` before the `transform`...]

Comment: @CollioTV You said a cast from a lambda to std::function can't be directly done. This is wrong. In this case, **both** casting **and** type-deduction can't be done **simultaneously**. But that's not specific to lambda or std::function. It's a general problem with function parameter whose type involves a template parameter + the passed object has to be converted first to match the parameter type "pattern".

Comment: @leemes yep' the error was mine, i just followed what my compiler said to me.... without thinking that the error could be elsewere... i'm sorry><

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Option #1:

Basic `decltype()` usage:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
auto select(const std::vector<T>& c, F f)
    -> std::vector<decltype(f(c[0]))>
{
    using R = decltype(f(c[0]));
    std::vector<R> v;
    std::transform(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::back_inserter(v), f);
    return v;
}
```

#### Option #2:

Basic `std::result_of<T>` usage:

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename R = typename std::result_of<F&(T)>::type>
std::vector<R> select(const std::vector<T>& c, F f)
{
    std::vector<R> v;
    std::transform(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::back_inserter(v), f);
    return v;
}
```

#### Option #3:

Advanced `decltype()` usage and *perfect-forwarding* (see notes*):

```
template <typename T, typename A, typename F>
auto select(const std::vector<T, A>& c, F&& f)
    -> std::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<typename std::decay<F>::type&>()(*c.begin()))>::type>
{
    using R = typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<typename std::decay<F>::type&>()(*c.begin()))>::type;
    std::vector<R> v;
    std::transform(std::begin(c), std::end(c)
                 , std::back_inserter(v)
                 , std::forward<F>(f));
    return v;
}
```

#### Option #4:

Advanced `std::result_of<T>` usage and *perfect-forwarding* (see notes*):

```
template <typename T, typename A, typename F, typename R = typename std::decay<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<F>::type&(typename std::vector<T, A>::const_reference)>::type>::type>
std::vector<R> select(const std::vector<T, A>& c, F&& f)
{
    std::vector<R> v;
    std::transform(std::begin(c), std::end(c)
                 , std::back_inserter(v)
                 , std::forward<F>(f));
    return v;
}
```

---

*** Note:** Options #3 and #4 assume that the `std::transform` algorithm takes a function object *by-value*, and then uses it as a non-const lvalue. This is why one can see this strange `typename std::decay<F>::type&` syntax. If the function object is supposed to be called within the `select` function itself, and the result type is not going to be used as a container's template argument (for the purpose of what the *outer-most* `std::decay<T>` is used), then the correct and portable syntax for obtaining the return type is:

```
/*#3*/ using R = decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(*c.begin()));

/*#4*/ typename R = typename std::result_of<F&&(typename std::vector<T, A>::const_reference)>::type
```

Comment: The "minor" improvement makes it look better, IMO.

Comment: I personally also prefer to abuse template parameters for "typedefs for use in the signature", in particular when they're also needed in the body. ;) That's IMHO nicer than trailing return type (but keep in mind that it's technically something different: it really adds template parameters although you usually don't need to care about them).

Answer (score 12):

Your first problem is that you think that a lambda is a `std::function`.  A `std::function` and a lambda are unrelated types.  `std::function<R(A...)>` is a type erasure object that can convert anything that is (A) copyable, (B) destroyable and (C) can be invoked using `A...` and returns a type compatible with `R`, and erases all other information about the type.

This means it can consume completely unrelated types, so long as they pass those tests.

A lambda is an anonymous class which is destroyable, can be copied (except in C++14, where this is sometimes), and has an `operator()` which you specify.  This means you can often convert a lambda into a `std::function` with a compatible signature.

Deducing the `std::function` from the lambda is not a good idea (there are ways to do it, but they are bad ideas: C++14 `auto` lambdas break them, plus you get needless inefficiency.)

So how do we solve your problem?  As I see it, your problem is taking a function object and a container and deducing what kind of element `transform` would produce after applying the function object on each element, so you can store the result in a `std::vector`.

This is the answer that is closest to the solution to your problem:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename Selector>
std::vector<R> select(std::vector<T> const & c, Selector s) {
  std::vector<R> v;
  std::transform(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::back_inserter(v), s);
  return v;
}
```

The easiest thing to do is swap `T` and `R` in template order, and have the caller pass in `R` explicitly, like `select<double>`.  This leaves `T` and `Selector` being deduced.  This isn't ideal, but it does do a small improvement.

For a full solution, there are two ways to approach fixing this solution.  First, we can change `select` to return a temporary object with an `operator std::vector<R>`, delaying the transformation to that point.  Here is an incomplete sketch:

```
template<typename T, typename Selector>
struct select_result {
  std::vector<T> const& c;
  Selector s;
  select_result(select_result&&)=default;
  select_result(std::vector<T> const & c_, Selector&& s_):
    c(c_), s(std::forward<Selector>(s_)
  {}
  operator std::vector<R>()&& {
    std::vector<R> v;
    std::transform(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::back_inserter(v), s);
    return v;
  }
};
template<typename T, typename Selector>
select_result<T, Selector> select(std::vector<T> const & c, Selector&& s) {
  return {c, std::forward<Selector>(s)};
}
```

I can also provide [a slicker version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c71c123a83b52dca) that sadly relies on undefined behavior (reference capture of local references in a function have lifetime issues under the standard).

But that gets rid of `auto v = select` syntax -- you end up storing the thing that produces results, rather than the results.

You can still do `std::vector<double> r = select( in_vec, [](int x){return x*1.5;} );` and it works pretty well.

Basically I have split deduction into two phases, one for arguments, and one for return value.

However, there is little need to rely on that solution, as there are other more direct ways.

For a second approach, we can deduce `R` ourselves:

```
template<typename T, typename Selector>
std::vector<typename std::result_of<Selector(T)>::type>
select(std::vector<T> const & c, Selector s) {
  using R = typename std::result_of<Selector(T)>::type;
  std::vector<R> v;
  std::transform(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::back_inserter(v), s);
  return v;
}
```

which is a pretty solid solution.  A touch of cleanup:

```
// std::transform takes by-value, then uses an lvalue:
template<class T>
using decayed_lvalue = typename std::decay<T>::type&; 
template<
  typename T, typename A,
  typename Selector,
  typename R=typename std::result_of<decayed_lvalue<Selector>(T)>::type
>
std::vector<R> select(std::vector<T, A> const & c, Selector&& s) {
  std::vector<R> v;
  std::transform(begin(c), end(c), back_inserter(v), std::forward<Selector>(s));
  return v;
}
```

makes this a serviceable solution.  (moved `R` to `template` type lists, allowed alternative allocators to the `vector`, removed some needless `std::`, and did perfect forwarding on the `Selector`).

However, we can do better.

The fact that the input is a `vector` is pretty pointless:

```
template<
  typename Range,
  typename Selector,
  typename R=typename std::result_of<Selector(T)>::type
>
std::vector<R> select(Range&& in, Selector&& s) {
  std::vector<R> v;
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  std::transform(begin(in), end(in), back_inserter(v), std::forward<Selector>(s));
  return v;
}
```

which doesn't compile due to the inability to determine `T` as yet.  So lets work on that:

```
namespace details {
  namespace adl_aux {
    // a namespace where we can do argument dependent lookup on begin and end
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    // no implementation, just used to help with ADL based decltypes:
    template<class R>
    decltype( begin( std::declval<R>() ) ) adl_begin(R&&);
    template<class R>
    decltype( end( std::declval<R>() ) ) adl_end(R&&);
  }
  // pull them into the details namespace:
  using adl_aux::adl_begin;
  using adl_aux::adl_end;
}
// two aliases.  The first takes a Range or Container, and gives
// you the iterator type:
template<class Range>
using iterator = decltype( details::adl_begin( std::declval<Range&>() ) );
// the second is syntactic sugar on top of `std::iterator_traits`:
template<class Iterator>
using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
```

which gives us an `iterator<Range>` and `value_type<Iterator>` aliases.  Together they let us deduce `T` easily:

```
// std::transform takes by-value, then uses an lvalue:
template<class T>
using decayed_lvalue = typename std::decay<T>::type&; 

template<
  typename Range,
  typename Selector,
  typename T=value_type<iterator<Range&>>,
  typename R=typename std::result_of<decayed_lvalue<Selector>(T)>::type
>
std::vector<R> select(Range&& in, Selector&& s) {
  std::vector<R> v;
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  std::transform(begin(in), end(in), back_inserter(v), std::forward<Selector>(s));
  return v;
}
```

and [bob is your uncle](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a394ba4cc899772).  (`decayed_lvalue` reflects how the `Selector` type is used for corner cases, and `iterator<Range&>` reflects that we are getting an iterator from the lvalue version of `Range`).

In VS2013 sometimes the above `decltype`s confuse the half-implementation of C++11 they have.  Replacing `iterator<Range>` with `decltype(details::adl_begin(std::declval<Range>()))` as ugly as that is can fix that issue.

```
// std::transform takes by-value, then uses an lvalue:
template<class T>
using decayed_lvalue = typename std::decay<T>::type&; 

template<
  typename Range,
  typename Selector,
  typename T=value_type<decltype(details::adl_begin(std::declval<Range&>()))>,
  typename R=typename std::result_of<decayed_lvalue<Selector>(T)>::type
>
std::vector<R> select(Range&& in, Selector&& s) {
  std::vector<R> v;
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  std::transform(begin(in), end(in), back_inserter(v), std::forward<Selector>(s));
  return v;
}
```

The resulting function will take arrays, vectors, lists, maps, or custom written containers, and will take any transformation function, and produce a vector of the resulting type.

The next step is to make the transformation lazy instead of putting it directly into a `vector`.  You can have `as_vector` which takes a range and writes it out to a vector if you need to get rid of lazy evaluation.  But that is getting into writing an entire library rather than solving your problem.

Comment: I know lambda is not a `std::function`, but you are absolutely right that I messed the arguments, and is should have been `R(T)` and not `T(R)`. Thank you for the informative answer.

Comment: @MariusBancila Edited your post, as `T(R)` and `R(T)` are not central to your problem.  Added a sketch of the "return magic object" technique.  Improved the other solution as well, made it less crufty, and including an explicit version that I think will work in VS2013U1-U3.  I left the commentary about `std::function` up there, because that is pretty central to why your attempts failed, and might be useful to someone else.

Comment: Regarding your `operator std::vector<R>()&&`: Isn't returning an rvalue reference of local values (which is happening here, right?) considered a bad idea? I'd be glad to know more about returning rvalue references... Any suggestion for a good read? Thanks.

Comment: @Yakk I didn't really understand what you want to say... What does  `operator std::vector<R>()&&` mean? Only just now I saw that the `&&` are behind `()`; does this mean `this` is a `&&` and the type to be converted to is a value?

Comment: @leemes yes.  rvalue refernce to `this`, returns a value copy.

Comment: @Yakk consider that `std::result_of<Selector(T)>::type` with `Selector` being *forwarding-reference* is invalid for number of reasons: **1.** it maintains *cv*-qualifiers, while `operator()` might not be `const`, **2.** `operator()` can have *ref*-qualifiers as well, while `Selector` is used as rvalue reference in `result_of` trait, **3.** `std::transform` algorithm takes functor by value, so it operates always on lvalue (after it drops cv-qualifiers and references). that said, it should be `std::result_of<typename std::decay<Selector>::type&(T)>::type`

Comment: failing examples: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebfa2882a991a263 and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f58f6d1abaa8fdca

Comment: @PiotrS. Fixed that I think, and also `iterator<Range>`.  Bundled the decay-lvalue into a single helper, as putting that much gymnastics on that line would be a distraction.