# Return type of function call on template argument class

Tags: templates, c++11, decltype

I am frequently finding myself dealing with templates and return values of functions in said templates. And I invariably end up with something like this:

```
template<typename Data>
auto foo(const Data& d) ->
    typename std::decay<decltype(reinterpret_cast<const Data*>(0)->operator()(0, 0))>::type
{
    typedef typename std::decay<decltype(reinterpret_cast<const Data*>(0)->operator()(0, 0))>::type return_t;
    ...
}
```

While this works, it is ugly and not really obvious what I want from a quick look. Is there a more readable, less 'hackish' way to get "the return type of calling this method on the template argument" ?

Comment: are you sure you want to decay the type, or it can be same as declared for `operator()` ?

Comment: In this case I want to decay it. Even if `operator ()` returns a `const T&` I want to return a `T` because I'm creating new values by interpolation in this specific case.

Comment: can `Data` be a function, or it must be class with `operator()` ?

Comment: @PiotrS. Anything that is callable by means of `const Data& d; ...d(x,y);` .

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383517/how-to-deduce-the-return-type-of-a-function-object-from-parameters-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without alias templates [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11):

```
template <typename Data>
auto foo(const Data& d) -> typename std::decay<decltype(d(0, 0))>::type
{
    return {};
}
```

or:

```
template <typename Data
        , typename return_r = typename std::decay<
              typename std::result_of<const Data(int, int)>::type
          >::type>
return_r foo(const Data& d)
{
    return {};
}
```

---

With alias templates ([c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) or written by hand):

```
template <typename Data>
auto foo(const Data& d) -> std::decay_t<decltype(d(0, 0))>
{
    return {};
}
```

or:

```
template <typename Data
        , typename return_r = std::decay_t<std::result_of_t<const Data(int, int)>>>
return_r foo(const Data& d)
{
    return {};
}
```

Use [`std::invoke_result_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

Comment: First example works perfectly. However second causes trouble because some `Data` specify their operator as `operator()(unsigned int, unsigned int)` then the matching fails. *ugh* But the first is loads better any way :D